# Using user entered string to select specific attribute an object of another class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Not really sure how to start asking this question so here's some code.

```
def find_attendees_by_attribute(attribute, criteria)
    attribute = attribute.to_sym
    if is_accepted_attribute?(attribute)
        @attendee_list.each do |attendee|
            #How do I get attendee."attribute" here?
        end
    else
        puts "Sorry, not a good attribute."
    end
end

def is_accepted_attribute?(attempted_attribute)
    @attribute_list.include?(attempted_attribute)
end
```

So in the above code I have an Attendee class that has been pushed into the @attendee_list of this AttendeeList class. I'm only doing exact match search for now, I will add case-insensitive and whitespace removal after I get a basic functionality.

I want to have the entered attribute evaluated so that I can get that property from the attendees that are being searched in the block. Let me know if this isn't clear, I obviously lack the terminology of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What is the structure of `@attendee_list`?  If `@attendee_list[attendee]` is a hash, and attribute is one of the keys, `@attendee_list[attendee][attribute]` would provide the value of that attribute (key), for user attendee.  Note that the method `is_accepted_attribute?` really serves no purpose; `if @attribute_list.include?(attempted_attribute)` is perfectly clear.

Comment: @attendee_list is an array of 'Attendee' objects. I see what you're saying about the method though. I guess since I'm teaching myself using OOP I have a tendency to add things that others might not. Makes sense though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
attendee.send(attribute)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Is this a common problem? Is this the common solution or something you just thought would work? Thanks.

Comment: Calling method names that are determined at runtime is definitely I see often and find myself doing from time to time. I wouldn't unnecessarily, but if it makes sense go for it!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `respond_to?` to check if the attribute you are sending is valid for that object.  I am assuming `@attribute_list` is an instance of some class that has `attributes` and `methods`.

```
class User
  attr_accessor :name

  def search_name
    # some logic here
  end
end

u = User.new

#check if `u` can understand or work with search_name
u.respond_to?(:search_name) #=> true
u.respond_to?(:name) #=> true
u.respond_to?(:eat) #=> false
```